# touchscreen navigation

Tags: touch-screen

Im looking at methods for displaying navigation on a 17" screen touchscreen kiosk. The primary navigation would be for shopping and be quite complex, ie goes down quite a few levels. Could anyone offer any advice on best practice or methods of achieving this in a user friendly way?

For instance, how would you translate the navigation on www.johnlewis.com for example?

Answer (score 7):

IMO, if you want to do a great job, you need to completely redesign for a touchscreen -- not merely "translate" a website.  Will this be a browser-based app?

Even if a pinch-to-zoom capability is present, if I was designing the app, I would assume that most users will not realize that.  Consequently, you need to make buttons and links quite a bit larger to avoid the "fat finger" syndrome.  I don't see how you can accomplish this without a redesign.

Comment: Good points about "fat finger" and people not knowing about pinch zoom

Comment: Thanks.  I'd add another factor: demographics.  A website visitor has a minimum of tech savvy.  At the very least, she *knows* what a website is.  Kiosk users come from much more varied demographics, and may include, just to cite two examples:  a) people who have never used a computer, or worse, are computer-phobes, and  b) people with poor vision who would be seriously challenged with the johnlewis.com website.

Comment: I understand it would be a total redesign, the part I was looking for advice in would be how to translate the complex navigation with many categories, then sub categories on to a kiosk style interface.